# if statement with multiple conditions not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I was reading all of the posts about if statements but not of them seem to solve my issue. I'm writing a shell script and I need to validate the user's input for an operation (addition, subtraction, division). My code is as follows:

```
valid_operator(){
  if [[ "$operator" != "+"  ||  "$operator" != "-" || "$operator" != "/"]]; then
   echo "Sorry, $operator, ++ is not a valid operator. Please re-enter valid operator"
   main
  fi
}
```

Comment: Space missing before `]]`.

Comment: And what happens when you run this? Do you get an error message? What is it? As choroba said, you have a syntax error, so you _should_ be getting an error. Do you not?

Comment: What does `main` do in your code?

Comment: @Kusalananda main wraps another class (cal_val: calculates the value the user input) in a while loop so it continuously loops until the user inputs X as the exit condition. This class is wrapped in cal_val to continuously check if the operator entered is valid. (this is my first unix script pls be gentle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a syntax error due to a missing space before the `]]`, and IIUC you want `true` if `$operator` is NONE of the values tested? I tested the `if-then` part & this should work.

```bsh
valid_operator(){
  if [[ "$operator" != "+"  &&  "$operator" != "-" && "$operator" != "/" ]]; then
    echo "Sorry, $operator, ++ is not a valid operator. Please re-enter valid operator"
    main
  fi
}
```

A 3-input XOR gate :)

Comment: The function also does not return anything related to whether the operator is valid or not, and presumably, the call to `main` would be a recursive call. The flow of control through this script may have to be revisited.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I'm sure you're correct, but I've no info on what he's doing beyond the evaluation of `$operator`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it worked. I got confused by the gates silly me.